# Forgot my Username feature - community users can't remember their username

Tags: community, forgot-your-password

Has anyone built a feature to retrieve a user's username?  There is a Forgot my Password but you have to provide your username.  In our partner community we've had to get creative with the usernames due to the uniqueness requirement across SF partner orgs.  So now our partners can't figure out what their username is.

I was thinking of a VF page where you enter your email, then the page checks for active users with that email and if none, shows an error.  If found, it could trigger a templated email to their email with their username.  Has anyone done this before or have suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you suggested is totally feasible, even though I haven't tried it. Usually in such cases I implemented Google/Facebook bases Single Sign On.